# Autofilter for multiple fields in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply an autofilter to a set of data that filters by two columns.  Is there a more efficient way than what I've written below that processes both fields in one statement rather than having to write another block that's effectively the same and making the code quite lengthy?

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter _
Field:=5, _
Criteria1:="1", _
VisibleDropDown:=True

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter _
Field:=6, _
Criteria1:=">0", _
VisibleDropDown:=True
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to compress it, but I do know you can compress visual space by putting them all of them same line - ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$50000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">2.5", for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 5, "1"
    .AutoFilter 6, ">0"
End With
```

You can add back in the identifier if you like. `VisibleDropDown = True` by default so you it's not needed.

Otherwise, you cannot AutoFilter multiple fields in the same line.